# Entity Framework : adding to one-to-many relationship gives concurrency exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to add to a one-to-many relationship. Once I try to save the newly created product using

```
context.saveChangesAsync() 
company.Products.Add(x)
```

It won't allow me to - I get an exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I can't figure out where it's being modified. I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
public async Task<Result<ProductDto>> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var company = await _context.Companies
                                .Include(x => x.Products)
                                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.UserId == _userAccessor.GetUserId());
        
    if (company != null)
    {
        var productToAdd = new Product
                               {
                                  Name = request.Product.Name,
                                  Description = request.Product.Description,
                                  SalePrice = request.Product.SalePrice,
                               };
                
        company.Products.Add(productToAdd);

        var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
                
        if (!result)  
           return Result<ProductDto>.Failure("failed to create product");
    }
            
    return Result<ProductDto>.Success(request.Product);
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }
    public int VatPercentage { get; set; } = 25;
}

public class Company : BaseEntity
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string TaxId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public AppUser User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

I don't know why and can't seem to find the issue and what I'm doing wrong. My builder relationship are set:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Domain.Entities.Company", b =>
    {
        b.Navigation("Products");
    });
 
 b.HasOne("Domain.Entities.Company", "Company")
                        .WithMany("Products")
                        .HasForeignKey("CompanyId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();
 
 b.Navigation("Company");
```

Comment: Have you tried awaiting the saveChangesAsny call?

Comment: Yes, I already have that in the code sample above. await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, this way you don't need to use  .Include(x => x.Products) to load the list of all products. It can save some network traffic and time. And add to list of products will  work for a new company. When you donwload an existing  company, ef tracks it and  sometimes gives an excepton .

```
    
    if (company != null)
    {
        var productToAdd = new Product
                               {
                                 CompanyId=company.Id,

                                  Name = request.Product.Name,
                                  Description = request.Product.Description,
                                  SalePrice = request.Product.SalePrice,
                               };
                
        _context.Products.Add(productToAdd);

        var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                
        if (result == 0)  
           return Result<ProductDto>.Failure("failed to create product");
    }
```

Comment: Great answer, with M:N or self/recursive relationships inserts are best handled with Ids if you have them and adding to the context directly rather than adding to the entity, but bonus points for picking up the absurdity of loading the entire product collection, for the customer just to add a new product. The only time you might consider loading the navigation property is even when you have complex logic that requires the other records, try to avoid such a requirement ;)

Comment: It works when I'm adding the product directly to the products table and specify companyId while adding it. 

But when I'm adding it from the company it gives the exception. Even if I'm not loading the relationship.

Comment: @Haruuun Yes, it will be , I explained why.  It doesn't matter if you included products or not , since the company is tracked, not products. And if you not included products and try to add a new one to an existed company you will certainly get ef error too. So if a company already exist, the best way is to  add new product directly to dbcontext. Products.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Thanks for the explaining @Serge